# The limit of $\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I have to find the limit of the sequence above.

Firstly, I tried to multiply out $n^3$, as it has the largest exponent.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3(1-\frac{3}{n^3})}{n^3(\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3})} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{3}{n^3}}{\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3}}$$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\frac{3}{n^3} = 1 \\[1ex]
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3} = 0 \\[1ex]
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} = \frac{1}{0}
\end{align}
$$

Then, after realizing $\frac{1}{0}$ might not be a plausible limit, I tried to multiply out the variable with the largest exponent in both the dividend and the divisor.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3(1 - \frac{3}{n^3})}{n^2(2 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2})} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac{1 - \frac{3}{n^3}}{2 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}}$$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\frac{3}{n^3} = 1 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}2 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2} = 2 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}n = \infty
\end{align}
$$

So, my questions about this problem:

- Could $\frac{1}{0}$ be a valid limit?
- Does $\infty\cdot\frac{1}{2}$
  equal to $\infty$?
- In conclusion, what is the limit of the sequence
  above? $\infty?$

Thank you!

Comment: Seeing $1/0$ makes me queasy. I'd say the sequence has no limit, since it **diverges** to $\infty$.

Comment: You are correct that the limit diverges as $\deg(\text{numerator})>\deg(\text{denominator})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Could $\frac{1}{0}$ be a valid limit?**
>
> You should be asking instead :"Is the following true?"  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$$
> where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = K $, where $K$ is finite and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(n) = +\infty$. The answer is yes. This is one of the limit rules.

---

> **Does $\infty \frac{1}{2}$ equal to $\infty$?**
> You should be asking instead:"Is the following true?"  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} K f(n)= \infty$$
> where $K$ is finite and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = +\infty$. The answer is yes. This is one of the limit rules.

---

> **In conclusion, what is the limit of the sequence above?**
>
> Following the same steps as you did, in both approaches, I have nothing to add. The limit is $\infty$.

Comment: The boxed texts everywhere make your answer hard to read for me.

Answer (score 3):

The second way is preferable and since the product "$\infty \cdot \frac12$" is not an indeterminate form from here

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac{1 - \frac{3}{n^3}}{2 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

we can conclude that the sequence diverges.

Note that also with the first method from here

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{3}{n^3}}{\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3}}$$

since also  "$\frac1 0$" is not an indeterminate form and the denominator is $>0$ we can conclude that the sequence diverges at $\infty$.

In both cases, what we cannot do is to calculate separetely the limit of each part and then make a direct calculation (that's allowed only is the final operation in well defined).

As an alternative since eventually

- $n^3-3\ge n^3-6n^2+9n \iff6n^2-9n-3\ge 0$
- $2n^2+n-1 \le 4n^2-24n+36\iff2n^2-25n+35 \ge 0$

by squeeze theorem we have

$$\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} \ge\frac{n^3-6n^2+9n}{4n^2-24n+36}=\frac{n(n-3)^2}{4(n-3)^2}=\frac n 4 \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

I admire your efforts, another approach is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3}{2n^2+n-1} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12n-\frac14+ \dfrac{\frac34n - \frac{13}{4}}{2n^2+n-1} \right) =\infty$$

Comment: I like your second approach best.

Comment: How do you verify your second equality? $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n}\stackrel{?}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Thank you for your kind words and for showing an other solution!

Comment: you are welcome. the first has an error. see above comment please.

Answer (score 2):

> So, my questions about this problem:
>
> - Could $\frac{1}{0}$ be a valid limit?

No, since $\frac10$ is not defined.

> - Does $\infty\cdot\frac{1}{2}$  equal to $\infty$?

There are the "extended real numbers" $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$

Where you can define this.
Note, that $\infty$ is in general not a number. So you can not do some calculations with it.
You can check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

For more informations.

> - In conclusion, what is the limit of the sequence
>   above? $\infty?$

Yes, the limit is $\infty$. Or in other words the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

- No, it's not valid, it is not defined. Consider two sequences: $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = \frac{1}{2^{-n}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = \frac{1}{-2^{-n}}$. You could say that limit of both of them is $\frac{1}{0}$, since $\pm2^{-n} \to 0$, but does this make sense? Do these sequences have the same limit?
- Saying that $\infty\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \infty$ is not very accurate, but your intuition is good. In general, for any sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ divergent to $+\infty$ and for any $x>0$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x\cdot a_n = +\infty$. What happens for $x < 0$?
- It is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

All you had expected, was solved by other solutions. I'd like to note some points. Maybe it has another taste. We know that for every natural number $n ≥ 1$, if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $a$, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\infty (-\infty)$$ whether $a$ is positive (negative). This means equally that, the limit of such polynomial at infinity, can be evaluated by the term which identify the order of $P(x)$. So at infinity, $$n^3-3\approx n^3,~~~2n^2+n−1\approx 2n^2$$ Now do the limit with the two result.

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything.I just want to represent it graphically.Then you will answer your own question.[image]
[image]

Now,you tell me.what are you seeing here?
And ofcourse the answer of your your questions is simply "yes".